# Angular pass reference variable from input type=file

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular and wrote a feature that displays a list of PDF files in my pdfs array.

The template parses them out in "card" elements in my template.

The error is when I try to pass the template variable "#file" into my (click)=query(pdf, file) expression.

My question is how to find the uploaded file's value? For instance, when i console.log(file) in my query() function, it always returns:
`<input accept=".pdf" placeholder="Upload file" type="file">`
I want the actual file's contents that the user selected.

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let pdf of pdfs">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="card-title-wrap bar-success">
        <h4 class="card-title">{{pdf.Link_Title}}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="px-3">
        {{pdf.Resource_Context_ID}}
      </div>
      <div class="px-3">
        {{pdf.Display_Name}}
      </div>
      <div class="px-3">
        {{pdf.Language_Code}}
      </div>

      <div class="px-3">
        <input type=file placeholder="Upload file" accept=".pdf" #file>
      </div>

      <div class="px-3">
        <button (click)=query"(pdf, file)"
          class="btn btn-primary btn-raised px-4 py-2 m-2 text-uppercase white font-small-4 box-shadow-2 border-0 float-left">
          update
        </button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Use query(pdf, file) in double quotation

Answer (score 0):

"query(pdf, file)" in double quotations worked.